# В каком типе данных хранить ip адреса пользователей в SQL MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, хранение-данных

В каком типе данных хранить ip адреса пользователей в SQL MySQL ?

Comment: Смотря что Вы с ним делать собираетесь и сколько этих записей, если просто просматирвать, то можно варчаром, если по нему будет фильтрация - то лучше целым числом. Если записей много, то число так же будет занимать меньше места

Comment: @cache Будет выборка по IP. Будем находить один IP. Колонка где будут записанны IP, с индексом уникальных значений.

Comment: @gilo1212, если так то посмотрите на дополнение в моем ответе, эти функции преобразуют айпишник в число - удобнее оперировать детальнее можете посмотреть вот тут http://expange.ru/e/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_(MySQL)

Comment: @Побежимов Борис может лучше так - BINARY(16) INET6_ATON и INET6_NTOA и соответственно - INET_NTOA() и INET6_ATON ?

Comment: @gilo1212 тогда однозначно формат должен быть числовым, а не varchar. Вот тут автор ответа советует использовать VARBINARY(16) вместо BINARY(16)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964143/storing-ipv6-addresses-in-mysql для поддерки IPV4+IPV6

Comment: @gilo1212 Здравствуйте! К какому варианту Вы пришли для хранения ip в базе данных? Тоже сейчас думаю, как правильнее будет)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Адреса **IPv4** храню в поле **int unsigned** в виде числа. Unsigned обязательно, чтобы на один знак больше влазил.

На жёстком диске занимает 4 байта. Что меньше чем char/varchar.

Для преобразования из строкового ip-адреса в число есть mysql функция `INET_ATON`:

```
mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('193.125.99.10');
+----------------------------+
| INET_ATON('193.125.99.10') |
+----------------------------+
|                 3246220042 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Для преобразования из числа в адрес - `INET_NTOA`.

1. Int вмещает до 2147483647
2. Int unsigned - до 4294967295

Выборки по диапазонам делать удобно. [Источник мой](http://jeka.by/ask/124/mysql-ip-address/#answer-75) :)

Хранить данные по ip в varchar - моветон, пригодный только для маленьких проектов. Если у вас миллион посетителей в день, из базы надо выжимать максимальную производительность, а памяти нужно использовать как можно меньше. Поскольку память - это деньги, циклы процессора - это деньги.

Миллион посетителей в день вполне может быть если вы делаете не магазинчик, а, допустим, рекламную сеточку, dsp, баннерокрутилку, платежную систему (свою или для банка) и т.д.

Миллион посетителей в день - это например, ваш выстреливший стартапчик, развернутый на AWS, лишняя сотня(тысяча?) баксов в месяц, которую вам может сэкономить такая оптимизация никогда не повредит.

Использование INET_NTOA/INET_ATON очень легкая, но важная оптимизация.

Когда вам потребуется обратиться к БД за айпишником, лучше делать преобразования inet_ntoa/inet_aton до запроса, в php/python/на_чем_вы_там_пишете чтобы использовались индексы бд.

P.S. про IPV6 - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81402 в версии 5.6 MySQL добавлены функции для работы с ним

Comment: А если кто-то захочет зайти с IPv6?

Comment: @gilo1212 Тогда не использовать int unsigned. IpV6 скорее будет если только в локальных сетях, а за натом ip будет обычный v4. В varchar(15) он все равно не влезет, надо varchar(39) как минимум.

Comment: И чего минусы, в чём ошибка?

Comment: Ответ хоть и дополнен, но не говорит как хранить и IPv4 и IPv6 в одном поле, и какого типа должно быть это поле.

Comment: скорее всего  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6965026/5006740, но я бы побенчмаркил для себя. желательно, на реальной нагрузке.

Answer (score 4):

мы храним в varchar, в принципе зачем что-то выдумывать для хранения айпишника?

можно конешно хранить как целые числа и использовать функции mysql INET_ATON() и INET_NTOA().

детальнее вот тут http://expange.ru/e/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_(MySQL)

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется что это не совсем правильно

Comment: мы тоже храним в varchar

Comment: почему? это стандартный вариант...

Comment: Так выбора будет долго происходить, по сравнению с BINARY(16)

Comment: А ipv6 как хранить?

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис это стандартный вариант для малонагруженных сайтов.

Comment: @strangeqargo, согласен с вами. Но изначально не было информации с какой конкретной целью. Поэтому первоочередных ответ не менял, просто добавил инфу о одном из вариантов в ответ.

Answer (score -2):

4 поля byte для IPv4

И места меньше занимает и оперировать проще

Comment: Неужели настолько плохой вариант? столько минусов...

Comment: @3per сам в шоке. Ладно бы хоть прокомментировали, что именно не нравится.