# Тип поля для ip адреса

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Какой тип поля необходимо назначать, поле которое будет содержать ip пользователя?

В данный момент назначаю VARCHAR, то есть строчку. Что та мне подсказывает что это неправильно. Поскольку поиск записи по строчке занимает большее время нежели если присвоили INT

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537968/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-ip-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-sql-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для хранения IP-адресов я советую INT, поскольку он занимает меньше места и имеет более быстрый поиск, чем VARCHAR. Поэтому можно сохранить IP-адрес в формате числа, используя функцию inet_aton.